# How to check Dataserver (under topology) connectivity in ODI 12c without logging in to ODI studio?

Tags: oracle-data-integrator

I want to run the scenario automatically by checking the dataserver connectivity in the backend.

Comment: [Is there something you have tried so far?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I have tried import topology via Java script.. but struck in checking the connectivity

Comment: Can you post your code so far?

Comment: is it possible to check the dataserver connectivity backend?

Comment: If i update SNP_CONNECT table with encoded password in PASS column, why is it not picking up for dataserver? PLease suggest @JeromeFr